# rename multiple images on upload

Tags: php

I am trying to rename multiple images on upload. I can upload and save them to a folder but I can't seem to rename them. Below my code and what I tried:

```
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');

$statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = '';
if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']))){
    foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){

        $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
        $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

        $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key],"uploads/".$fileName.time());
            //move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath);
        }else{
            $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';
        }
    }

}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;
```

Comment: **Well thats because you dont even attempt to rename them.**

Comment: You will have to do something a bit more clever with this line `$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;`

Comment: yes, didn't post the entire code. sorry.

Comment: see above edit what I have tried. I have puted a time varible at the end of the $filename but that was putting the number in the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
 $targetDir = "uploads/";
 $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');

 $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = '';
 if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']))){
     foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){

         $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
         $expFileName=explode(".",$fileName);
         $fileName=rand().".".$expFileName[1];
         $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

         $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
         if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key],$targetFilePath);
        //move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath);
         }else{
             $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';
         }
     }

 }else{
     $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
 }

 // Display status message
 echo $statusMsg;
 ?>
```